# iOS In App Purchases subscription is not returning any receipt in production

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

So this has been driving me crazy for a few days now. 
We implemented in app purchases subscriptions on an iOS app, we're validating on our server, so what we're doing is basically make the purchase and then send the receipt to our server to validate it and it's getting saved there in our db.
What's happening is that when testing in sandbox, everything is working perfectly well, we're getting the receipt, we're validating on the backend and we're saving/updating the returned data, but when we published the app on the app store, we faced a major issue which is that the payment is going through, and apple is charging the user, but no receipt.

I'm trying to retrieve the receipt with the following:

```
     func loadReceipt() -> Data? {

    guard let url = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL else {
        return nil
    }

    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        return data
    } catch {
        print("Error loading receipt data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return nil
    }
}

func uploadReceipt(productId: String, completion: @escaping ErrorCompletion) {
    if let receiptData = loadReceipt() {
        let receipt = Receipt()
        receipt.createdBy = User.current()
        receipt.receipt = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])

        print(receipt.receipt)

        validateReceipt(receipt: receipt.receipt!, productId: productId, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

I even tried to use `SKReceiptRefreshRequest()` if the receipt is nil and still no luck.

Anybody have ANY idea of what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a common mistake, what is the url you are using for validating your receipt ?

Comment: The validation on the server side is working properly, and I'm using the production URL not the sandbox, but the problem is that the app is not sending the receipt to be validated in the first place, so the issue is in the app not the backend, which is really weird and annoying

Comment: What is the purchased product's type and transaction state when you retrieve receipt data?

Comment: This is strange that it works in sandbox and not production.

Does the `validateReceipt` call happen to your backend at all in production?

Comment: @mmtootmm I'm not getting any receipt whatsoever, that's why It's driving me crazy :)

Comment: @JacobEiting no in production the function is not getting called at all, I did a real purchase 4 times already and none of them is triggering the function and I'm getting charged by apple for each transaction.

Comment: @Khalil Could you post the code that is supposed to call `uploadReceipt`? Is `uploadReceipt` getting called? Is the print getting hit?

Comment: @JacobEiting sure here is the code: 
    `private func seveReceiptIfPossible() {
        
        guard let transaction = lastSuccessfulTransaction else {
            return
        }
        
        let worker = SubscriptionsWorker()
        if User.current() != nil {
            worker.uploadReceipt(productId: transaction.payment.productIdentifier) { (error) in
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: SubscriptionsService.kNotification, object: error)
            }
        }   
    }`
   
Upload is called in sandbox, but no way to monitor prints in production

Comment: Hmm, yeah, there is a lot of places this could be failing.

You can see debug messages in production by connecting your device to your computer, Opening Xcode, Opening Devices and Simulators under Window menu, Select the device, and open the tray at the bottom to see all logs for a device.

Comment: @JacobEiting oh I had no idea I can see debug messages in production! this is gonna be greatly helpful if it works, I'll give it a test and let you know, thanks!

Comment: @JacobEiting this won't help apparently, it's switching to sandbox directly when I connect my device.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. You need to install and run the app from the app store and not build and run it from Xcode.

Comment: @JacobEiting that's what I did, as soon as my device is detected it's prompting for my apple id password along with a [Sandbox Enviornment] at the bottom. According to apple docs you can't possibly do that once the app is in production, you can only see crash logs, and crash logs don't help at all cause the app is not crashing, maybe they changed that? apple keep changing stuff every couple of weeks :)

Comment: @Khalil Are you logged in to a sandbox account in the AppStore?

Comment: @JacobEiting No no, I'm logged in to my personal account, and I'm downloading the production app, weirdly now I deleted the app again, and downloaded it one more time, and it's not giving me any sandbox thing, but there's nothing really showing in the logs, everything displayed is related to other installed apps, and they're all related to crashes, can I debug it just like I do in xcode's console? for example get the prints to be displayed at least?

Comment: Haha, not surprised, funky stuff happens when switching between App Store and debug builds. No you can't debug an App Store build unfortunately. You might try to copy and paste the logs and search them, your print statements should be there.

Comment: @JacobEiting Haha yea, tell me about it! 
I have a silly question now cause I just saw a youtube video about debugging apps in production and I think that's why I can't see anything related to my app! 
When I'm connecting my iPhone, the devices and simulators window is not actually displaying anything at all in terms of logs, unless I click on View Device Logs, now I have an "Installed Apps" section, and for some reason, nothing is displayed there except an app that is not actually mine! it's Pixir photo editing app and I have nothing to do with it haha what's going on??

Comment: @JacobEiting I got it to work, don't ask, but I deleted this Pixir app and suddenly all the logs are appearing! Thanks! I'll break my head with the logs now :)

Comment: @JacobEiting here are the two things that appeared when I removed my monthly subscription from itunes and then activated it again in the app: 

<Notice>: [AppReceipt] No receipt data for: <private>
<Notice>: MicroPaymentClient: Could not find payment to merge with existing payment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158787/discussion-between-jacob-eiting-and-khalil).